# Prevent double options in dropdown list

Tags: php, html

in my dropdown list I insert a value from a mySQL query. This Value is my selected Option. 
The problem is, that he duplicate my selected Value (it is logical because I create "6 Options" but the user only should have "5 Options").

How can I prevent this?

This is my Code:

```
  echo "<select id='qty' name='qty' onchange='this.form.submit()'>";
  echo "<option value='".$row['a_qty']."' selected>".$row['a_qty']."</option> ";
  echo "<option value='1'>1</option>";
  echo "<option value='2'>2</option>";
  echo "<option value='3'>3</option>";
  echo "<option value='4'>4</option>";
  echo "<option value='5'>5</option>";
  echo "</select>";
  echo "<script>
```

And my Output:

[image]

Comment: `($row['a_qty'] == 4) ? 'selected' : ''` Good luck.

Comment: @AnkiiG Please do not place unnecessary comments.

Comment: @AnkiiG questioner able to see your answer why you post unnecessary comments

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try as below :

```
echo "<select id='qty' name='qty' onchange='this.form.submit()'>";
for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++)
{
  $selected = '';
  if($i==$row['a_qty'])
    $selected = 'selected="selected"';
  echo "<option value='$i' $selected>$i</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
```